# php lost some path of string after submition using ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a comment using ajax post with php, it's working very fine as i expected it to but when i try to submit some sting that contain `&` it lossess path of the sting only show from beginging till where the and is.
I really don't know how to fix this, i have no idea about what is the problem please i need help.

See example

**MY ajax**

```
<script>
    $('#submitcomment').on('click', function(){
        try{
                    var message = $('.commentTextinput').val();
                    var key= $(this).attr('data-keyname');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: UrlExistsA('snippet/snippetcomment'),
                        data: 'message=' + message + '&key=' + key,
                        type: 'POST',
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $('#submitcomment').html('Wait....');
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('tr.replyList:last-child').after(data);
                            $('.commentTextinput').val('');
                            $('#submitcomment').html('Comment');
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            alert('Processing Error' + '<br/>' + data);
                        }                   
                    });                 
        }catch(err){alert(err.message);}
        finally{}
    });
</script>
```

**Here is test php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
$postReply = htmlentities($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo $postReply;

}
```

**The above will output this**

> tomorrow we will run faster, stretch out our arms farther... And then
>   one fine morning

**But the original string posted was**

> tomorrow we will run faster, stretch out our arms farther... And then
>   one fine morning— So we beat on, boats against the current,
>   borne back ceaselessly into the past.

also when i tried to submit `&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&` it return empty But when i echo the above string without using ajax it was very okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `encodeURIComponent` to encode special characters in the parameter string. `&` is the separator between parameters, so you need to encode it.

```
data: 'message=' + encodeURIComponent(message) + '&key=' + encodeURIComponent(key),
```

But a simpler way is to use an object instead of a string, then jQuery will encode it automatically.

```
data: { message: message, key: key },
```

Comment: what if the string is only one can i still add it as an object? `data: {id: id}`?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing special about that.